# Use JAXB Annotation With Value

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotations

When generating XML using JAXB annotations, I know it's not possible to use `@XmlElement(name="City")` & `@XmlValue` on the same Java member because they are mutually exclusive. **Is it possible to @XmlElement to produce an XML tag with a value at the same time?** Not being able to do this causes a ton of objects to be created and seems to be overkill.

**Java Code**

```
....
@XmlElement(name="City")
@XmlValue       <---- I'm wanting to do this but I'm limited by the API
private String city;
```

**Expected Output**

```
....
<City>some value here</City>
....
```

Comment: Doesn't `@XmlElement` have something like `defaultValue` as parameter, if that's what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm not looking for a default value in this case.

Answer (score 0):

We can try to achieve the same using another type which uses `@XmlValue` annotation.

Below is what you can try -

```
@XmlRootElement(name="CityRoot")
@XmlType(name="CityRootType")
public class CityRoot {
    @XmlElement(name="City")
    public CityName s;
}
```

`CityName` definition as below

```
public class CityName {
    @XmlValue
    String name;
}
```

Now, feed these two files to `schemagen` to have the `.xsd` file generated and using that generate `.xml` file to verify.

Below is how generated xml file looks like when I generated it -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CityRoot>
      <City>SomeCityName</City>
</CityRoot>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an element with simple text, the only annotation you need is the @XmlElement annotation. If the type of a field is String, JAXB generates an xml element with the value of the String as the value of the element.

The only thing you need is this:

```
@XmlElement(name="City")
private String city;
```